# first data payment gateway (premium)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, firstdata

I am using woo-commerce plugin for word press. I recently installed first data payment gateway extension(premium extension) into my wordpress.

It throws the following error:

> FirstData GGe4 Error: Credit card data cannot be entered unless you are using an SSL secured connection.

I am not sure what is SSL, how can I connect SSL with first data gateway.

Comment: you have to take SSL licence from your web hoster for yor site

Comment: @softsdev can i get SSL license for free or purchasing it is the only option?

Comment: you have to purchase it, its not free talk to your web host support they will help you

Comment: @softsdev  does all the websites need to purchase SSL certificate

Comment: no but some payment getaway needs SSL like Authorized.net firstdata for security

Comment: also check my updated answer if not work after installation of SSL

Comment: this is my site http://www.peroxywhite.com/checkout/ look at the checkout page first data showing error i was told you

Comment: yes that will solve once you install SSL

Comment: check docs of First data payment getaway here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/firstdata/ they mention  `FirstData allows your customers to enter their credit card info on your website during checkout. A valid SSL certificate is required `

Comment: brother one more thing  SSL certificate have to install godaddy web host or where to install

Comment: hello sir softsdev how are you can i have your help now

Comment: actually iahve done the SSL certication for my site and i am getting the first data payment gateway options in checkout page but when i give some dummy credit card details it is showing first data system error what is that i am not sure can you tell me

Comment: brother i am waiting for you reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to take **SSL licence** from your web hoster for yor site

After installation if that will not work then try to add below code in your function.php of theme for particular page with ssl

```
add_action('wp_head', 'apply_ssl_to_specific_page');
add_action('admin_head', 'apply_ssl_to_specific_page');
add_action('login_head', 'apply_ssl_to_specific_page');
function apply_ssl_to_specific_page(){
        <?php
    if ( is_page('your-checkout-page-slug') ) {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443')
            header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    } else {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') 
            header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }

}
```

replace **your-checkout-page-slug** with your page slug